# device is not in a usable state / try to create pv out of lv

Tags: debian, lvm, proxmox

i think its a newbie question, i try to create a nested lvm or stack lvm.
so i try to create a pv out of a lv, but i just get this message:

```
pvcreate /dev/SSD-Pool/raid1-ssd

Cannot use /dev/SSD-Pool/raid1-ssd: device is not in a usable state

root@node01:/dev/SSD-Pool# lvs -a
  LV                   VG       Attr       LSize   Pool      Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  base-101-disk-0      SSD-Pool Vri---tz-k  50.00g fast_thin
  base-105-disk-0      SSD-Pool Vri---tz-k  50.00g fast_thin
  fast_thin            SSD-Pool twi-aotz-- 600.00g                  23.42  22.24
  [fast_thin_tdata]    SSD-Pool Twi-ao---- 600.00g
  [fast_thin_tmeta]    SSD-Pool ewi-ao----  76.00m
  [lvol0_pmspare]      SSD-Pool ewi------- 112.00m
  raid1-ssd            SSD-Pool Rwi-a-r--- 223.56g                                         100.00
  [raid1-ssd_rimage_0] SSD-Pool iwi-aor--- 223.56g
  [raid1-ssd_rimage_1] SSD-Pool iwi-aor--- 223.56g
  [raid1-ssd_rmeta_0]  SSD-Pool ewi-aor---   4.00m
  [raid1-ssd_rmeta_1]  SSD-Pool ewi-aor---   4.00m
  vm-100-disk-0        SSD-Pool Vwi-aotz-- 120.00g fast_thin        84.50
  vm-102-disk-0        SSD-Pool Vwi-aotz--  50.00g fast_thin        48.69
  vm-103-disk-0        SSD-Pool Vwi-a-tz-- 100.00g fast_thin        1.64
  vm-104-disk-0        SSD-Pool Vwi-aotz--  10.00g fast_thin        92.72
  Backup               Stuff    -wi-ao---- 500.00g
  base-102-disk-0      Stuff    Vri---tz-k  50.00g myStuff
  base-108-disk-0      Stuff    Vri---tz-k  50.00g myStuff
  base-110-disk-0      Stuff    Vri---tz-k  50.00g myStuff
  [lvol0_pmspare]      Stuff    ewi------- 104.00m
  myStuff              Stuff    twi-aotz--  <6.35t                  3.10   11.91
  [myStuff_tdata]      Stuff    Twi-ao----  <6.35t
  [myStuff_tmeta]      Stuff    ewi-ao---- 104.00m
  vm-100-disk-0        Stuff    Vwi-aotz-- 120.00g myStuff          20.30
  vm-104-disk-0        Stuff    Vwi-a-tz--  50.00g myStuff          7.62
  vm-104-disk-1        Stuff    Vwi-a-tz--  50.00g myStuff          11.65
  vm-105-disk-0        Stuff    Vwi-a-tz-- 100.00g myStuff          20.42
  vm-106-disk-0        Stuff    Vwi-a-tz--  10.00g myStuff          100.00
  data                 pve      twi-a-tz--  59.66g                  0.00   1.59
  [data_tdata]         pve      Twi-ao----  59.66g
  [data_tmeta]         pve      ewi-ao----   1.00g
  [lvol0_pmspare]      pve      ewi-------   1.00g
  root                 pve      -wi-ao----  27.75g
  swap                 pve      -wi-ao----   8.00g
```

[pvcreate -vvvv output](https://pastebin.com/DJLfjNEX)

Any Idea how to troubleshoot or proceed?
Thanks!

Comment: Please add `lvs -a` output to your question and try running `pvcreate` with `-vvvv` to get more information. Also if this is a newly created RAID logical volume it's possible the initial resync is still in progress so the LV cannot be used.

Comment: Yep.  Attribute item 1, "(R)aid without initial sync"

Comment: Hi Thanks for your replay.
I added the information.
Its syncing, will try it again, after it finished.

Comment: Even after 100% sync, its the same error, i would be really thankful if somebody could just check the new output: https://pastebin.com/UnFXtGiE or give me some hints, how i could proceed. –

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you need to enable the `scan_lvs` option in your `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`

If this still doesn't work, the device might be filtered out, in which case you might need to tinker with the `filter` option.